# Pandas Start Week on Sunday when Using Group By for Dates and counting events in the period

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

I have some data and a date column. By running the command below, it goes through the DF and counts all the events happened during that week.

```
df['date'].groupby(df.date.dt.to_period("W")).agg('count')
```

The result is something like:

```
2018-04-16/2018-04-22    40
2018-04-23/2018-04-29    18
```

The weeks starts on Monday and end Sunday.

I want the week to start on Sunday and end on Saturday. So, the data should be

```
2018-04-15/2018-04-21    40
2018-04-22/2018-04-28    18
```

Comment: does `df.date.dt.to_period("W-MON")` work?

Comment: Well, I went the wrong way. Use "W-SAT".  See answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':np.random.choice(pd.date_range('2018-04-10',periods=365, freq='D'),1000)})

df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.to_period('W-SAT')).agg('count')
```

Output:

```
                       Date
Date                       
2018-04-08/2018-04-14    12
2018-04-15/2018-04-21    19
2018-04-22/2018-04-28    21
2018-04-29/2018-05-05    16
2018-05-06/2018-05-12    21
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an [anchored offset](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets). Excerpt from the linked table:

```
W-SUN   weekly frequency (Sundays). Same as ‘W’
W-MON   weekly frequency (Mondays)
W-TUE   weekly frequency (Tuesdays)
W-WED   weekly frequency (Wednesdays)
W-THU   weekly frequency (Thursdays)
W-FRI   weekly frequency (Fridays)
W-SAT   weekly frequency (Saturdays)
```

Since you want the week to end on Saturday, `W-SAT` should
suffice.